# How to solve this complicated trigonometric equation for the solution of this triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, if $AB=AC$ and internal bisector of angle $B$ meets $AC$ at $D$ such that $BD+AD=BC=4$, then what is $R$ (circumradius)?

[image]

My Approach:- I first drew the diagram and considered $\angle ABD=\angle DBC=\theta$ and as $AB=AC$, $\angle C=2\theta$.  Therefore $\angle A=180-4\theta$. Also as $AE$ is the angular bisector and $AB=AC$, then $BE=EC=2.$ Now applying the sine theorem to $\triangle ADB$ and  $ \triangle BDC$ gives $$\frac{BD}{\sin {(180-4\theta)}}=\frac{AD}{\sin \theta}$$

$$\frac{BC}{\sin(180-3\theta)}=\frac{BD}{\sin 2\theta}$$
Now we know that $BC=4$ and then solving both the equations by substituting in $BD+AD=4$, we get $$\sin 2\theta .\sin4\theta+\sin2\theta.\sin\theta=\sin3\theta.\sin4\theta$$
$$\sin4\theta+\sin\theta=\frac{\sin3\theta.\sin4\theta}{\sin2\theta}$$
Now I have no clue on how to proceed further from here. Though I tried solving the whole equation into one variable ($\sin\theta$), but it's getting very troublesome as power of $4$ occurs. Can anyone please help further or else if there is any **alternative method** to solving this problem *more efficiently* or *quickly*?
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you are proceeding correctly. The equation can be solved as follows:
$$\sin 2\theta \sin \theta=\sin 4\theta(\sin 3\theta-\sin 2\theta) {\tag 1}$$
Now $\sin 3\theta-\sin 2\theta=2\cos \frac {5\theta}{2} \sin \frac {\theta}{2}$.

Also $\sin \theta=2\cos \frac {\theta}{2} \sin \frac {\theta}{2}$, and $\sin 4\theta=2\sin 2\theta \cos 2\theta$.
So, $(1)$ simplifies to:
$$\cos \frac {\theta}{2}=2\cos \frac {5\theta}{2}\cos 2\theta {\tag 2}$$
Since $2\cos \frac {5\theta}{2} \cos 2\theta=\cos \frac {9\theta}{2}+\cos \frac {\theta}{2}$, we have, from $(2)$:
$$\cos \frac {9\theta}{2}=0$$
This means that $\frac {9\theta}{2}=\frac {\pi}{2}$, hence $\theta=\frac {\pi}{9}$.
This means that all angles of triangle are known, and we know $BC=4$. Thus using sine law, $$2R=\frac {BC}{\sin A}$$ is easy to calculate.

Comment: Understood @Ritam_Dasgupta, Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think this is quite complete.  You can't go from $\cos 9\theta/2 = 0$ to $9\theta/2  = \pi/2$ as there are other solutions, which you have to eliminate.

Comment: True, I  didn't mention it, but it's quite simple really. General solution is $\theta=\frac {(2n+1)\pi}{9}$, and $0<\theta <\frac {\pi}{4}$, since $\angle A>0$, so only this solution is possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such a method. Making use of Mathematica command

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[Sin[2*\[Theta]]*Sin[4*\[Theta]] + 
 Sin[2*\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]] == 
Sin[3*\[Theta]]*Sin[4*\[Theta]] && \[Theta] > 0 && \[Theta] < 
Pi, \[Theta]] // ToRadicals]
```

, one obtains
$$3 \theta =\pi \lor 2 \theta =\pi \lor 9 \theta =\pi \lor 9 \theta =5 \pi \lor 9 \theta =7 \pi.$$

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't learnt this yet. Of course, in future, I will try to learn this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The values are such that equations do not simplify. Nonetheless, here is an alternate approach.

Say $AB = AC = x$ and we know $BC = 4$,

By angle bisector theorem,

$\cfrac{4}{x} = \cfrac{x-AD}{AD} \implies AD = \cfrac{x^2}{4+x}$

Now by angle bisector length formula,

$BD^2 = \cfrac{4x}{(4+x)^2} [(4+x)^2 - x^2] = \cfrac{32x(x+2)}{(4+x)^2}$

Now, $BD + AD = 4 = \cfrac{x^2}{4+x} + \cfrac{\sqrt{32x(x+2)}}{4+x}$

$16+4x-x^2 = \sqrt{32x(x+2)}$

Solving using WolframAlpha, the only valid solution is $x \approx 2.61$

Now to find circumradius, use $R = \cfrac{abc}{4 \triangle} = \cfrac{4 x^2}{8 \sqrt{x^2 - 4}}$

Comment: Understood @MathLover, thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome!